# Handle Complex Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following tables with their columns

- tbAgent :- Agent, AgentX, AgentCode, NIPRNumber, PhysicalAddressState,
  SystemUser
- tbBroker :- Broker, BusinessName, BrokerCode,SystemUser
- tbCompany :- Company, CompanyX
- tbSystemUser :- SystemUser FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress
- tbProduct :- Product, ProductX, ProductCode, Jurisdiction,  CompanyId
- tbLicence :- Licence, LicenceNumber,DateIssued,ExpirationDate,Jurisdiction,
  StateIssued, BrokerId, AgentId
- tbCompanyAgent :- CompanyId, AgentId, ProductId, LicenseNumber,
  LicenseIssueDate,LicenceExpirationDate
- tbBrokerAgent :- BrokerId, AgentId
- tbJurisdiction :- Jurisdiction, JurisdictionX

In this project, we store Agents, Agencies (Brokers) and Companies in tbAgent, tbBroker and tbCompany respectively. We store Company's Products in tbProduct.
Thr Agent's LicenseDetails are stored in tbLicence. Agent's are appointed to  Agencies(Brokers) and these details are stored in tbBrokerAgent.
Also Agents are appointed to Companies and these details are stored in tbCompanyAgent. The Agents are appointed to Companies, if Company's product's Jurisdiction matched with the Agent's License's Resident State or Non Resident state.

Note that Agent's has two type of licences stored in tbLicence, one is Resident and other is Non Resident Licenses. If it is Resident License, then the column name "Jurisdiction" contains 0 and If it is Non Resident License, then it contain   actual Jurisdiction Id of State. If it contains 0 then we have to consider Agent's PhysicalAddressState as ResidentState.

All jurisdictions (States) are present in tbJurisdiction.

Now I have to create a view where I have to fetch the following Information

- CompanyX
- CompanyCode
- BrokerX
- BrokerCode
- AgentX
- Agentcode
- NIPRNumber
- ProductX
- ProductCode
- State
- LicenceNumber
- EffectiveDate
- ExpirationDate

I have tried the following query

```
          SELECT a.AgentCode,sy.AgentName,L.Licence,L.LicenceNumber,DateIssued as EffectiveDate,L.ExpirationDate,J.JurisdictionX as State
  From tbAgent as a
  INNER JOIN tbLicence L ON L.AgentId=a.Agent
   LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Jurisdiction,JurisdictionX FROM tbJurisdiction) as  j on j.Jurisdiction=
   (
   CASE WHEN ISNULL(L.Jurisdiction,'0')='0' THEN a.PhysicalAddressState
   ELSE
   L.Jurisdiction
   END
  )
  LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT SystemUser, (FirstName + ' '+LastName) as AgentName FROM tbSystemUser ) as sy on sy.SystemUser=a.SystemUser
```

The above query is fetching the following information

- AgentX
- Agentcode
- NIPRNumber
- State
- LicenceNumber
- EffectiveDate
- ExpirationDate

Excluding the following columns

- CompanyX
- CompanyCode
- BrokerX
- BrokerCode
- ProductX
- ProductCode

I am not able to tweak the above query for fetching the excluding Column's information  because the query is getting complex to handle...

Please help me !!!

Comment: Confirm broker/agent table.. Is this a CURRENT BROKER only
in case an agent moved from one broker to another?  The LICENSE table also has the pair information on a per agent/broker and the respective license jurisdictions and expiration info?  Can an agent work for multiple brokers?  What are the qualifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is about complexity, I hope CTE-technique will be a good tip for you:

```
;WITH cteJur as 
(
  SELECT
    Jurisdiction,
    JurisdictionX
  FROM tbJurisdiction j
),
cteSysUsr as
(
  SELECT
    SystemUser,
    (FirstName + ' '+LastName) as AgentName
  FROM tbSystemUser su
),
cteAgent as
(
  SELECT
    a.AgentCode, a.SystemUser,
    L.Licence, L.LicenceNumber,
    L.DateIssued as EffectiveDate, L.ExpirationDate,
    CASE
      WHEN ISNULL(L.Jurisdiction,'0')='0'
      THEN a.PhysicalAddressState
      ELSE L.Jurisdiction
    END as Jurisdiction
  FROM tbAgent as a
  INNER JOIN tbLicence L ON L.AgentId=a.Agent
)
SELECT
  a.AgentCode, sy.AgentName,
  a.Licence, a.LicenceNumber,
  a.EffectiveDate, a.ExpirationDate,
  J.JurisdictionX as State
FROM tbAgent as a
LEFT JOIN cteJur as j on j.Jurisdiction = a.Jurisdiction
LEFT JOIN cteSysUsr as sy on sy.SystemUser = a.SystemUser
```

If you were looking where to include your "excluded columns" - add them into appropriate CTE and reference them in final select. You don't have to put every joined table into a subquery. Just join it and reference table's columns in select list, that's it. Just as described in the query above.

Answer (score 1):

First, you appear to have a good following of the tables and how related.  I have tried to implement them and get ALL columns from the respective table(s).  You can strip out whatever you want.

Now, first, I want you to look at the FROM clause section.  Think of this before getting the columns, especially in a complex query of a lot of tables being joined.  Take each one to the next.  I always try to do my joins with the first table (or alias) as the left-side of the ON clause and the JOINING TO as the right-side... Then, if something is nested under the second, I keep the indentation going so I see the literal correlations more directly and have less chance of getting confused.

```
from
   FirstTable alias1
      JOIN SecondTable alias2
         on alias1.IDColumn = alias2.IDColumn
         JOIN ThirdTable alias3
            on alias2.OtherID = alias3.OtherID
```

Now, in the case of your Jurisdictions, there are 3 possible places it CAN originate from... The agent, product and the license.  Because I do not know which version you specifically want, I applied LEFT-JOINs to each one respectively.  This allows me to use the same table multiple times with different aliases.  Then I grab each JurisdictionX and call it an appropriate "as" name in the result.

Finally, I build out all the field columns that are wanted.  If you wanted to narrow the list of data (such as a single broker) then you just apply the WHERE criteria.  Hopefully this makes a lot of sense and you can strip out the extra fields you may not care about.

```
SELECT
      a.Agent,
      a.AgentX,
      a.AgentCode,
      a.NIPRNumber,
      a.PhysicalAddressState,
      a.SystemUser,
      ( AgUser.FirstName + ' '+ AgUser.LastName) as AgentName,
      AgUser.EmailAddress as AgentEMail,
      b.Broker,
      b.BusinessName,
      b.BrokerCode,
      b.SystemUser as BrokerUser,
      ( BrUser.FirstName + ' '+ BrUser.LastName) as BrokerName,
      BrUser.EmailAddress as BrokerEMail,
      l.License,
      l.LicenseNumber,
      l.DateIssued,
      l.ExpirationDate,
      l.Jurisdiction,
      l.StateIssued,
      ca.LicenseNumber as CA_LicenseNumber,
      ca.LicenseIssueDate as LicenseIssueDate,
      ca.LicenseExpirationDate as LicenseExpirationDate,
      c.Company,
      c.CompanyX,
      p.ProductX,
      p.ProductCode,
      AgJuris.JurisdictionX as AgentJurisdiction,
      LicJuris.Jurisdiction as LicenseJurisdiction,
      ProdJuris.Jurisdiction as ProductJurisdiction
   from
      tbAgent a
         JOIN tbSystemUser AgUser
            ON a.SystemUser = ag.SystemUser

           JOIN tbLicense l
              ON a.Agent = l.AgentID
              JOIN tbBroker B
                 ON l.BrokerID = B.BrokerID

               JOIN tbSystemUser BrUser
                  ON b.SystemUser = br.SystemUser

               LEFT JOIN tbJurisdiction LicJuris
                  ON ISNULL(L.Jurisdiction,'0') = LicJuris.Jurisdiction

         JOIN tbCompanyAgent ca
            ON a.Agent = ca.AgentID

            JOIN tbCompany c
               ON ca.CompanyID = c.Company

            JOIN tbProduct p
               ON ca.CompanyID = p.CompanyID
               AND ca.ProductID = p.Product

               LEFT JOIN tbJurisdiction ProdJuris
                  ON p.Jurisdiction = ProdJuris.Jurisdiction

         LEFT JOIN tbJurisdiction AgJuris
            ON a.PhysicalAddressState = AgJuris.Jurisdiction
```

Additionally, for the issue on Jurisdictions, since you have all 3 POSSIBLE, you could add a last column such as

```
COALESCE( LicJuris.Jurisdiction, AgJuris.JurisdictionX ) as WhichJurisdiction
```

or considering all 3...

```
COALESCE( LicJuris.Jurisdiction, COALESCE( ProdJuris.Jurisdiction , AgJuris.JurisdictionX )) as WhichJurisdiction
```

So, if the license jurisdiction is not available, grab the value from product jurisdiction, if not that, fall back to the agent's jurisdiction.